# Observe in vs observe about vs observe of

Tags: grammar

This came out of a casual conversation with a friend - and now all three sound correct to us; could someone please confirm if it’s correct to say - 
1. I observed this about you, or
2. I observed this in you, or
3. I observed this of you

Answer (score 3):

**observe** can mean "see, detect" or "say something in regard to".   With **of** I'd take you to mean the latter, with **in** the former, and with **about** either.

Comment: Ahh, that means all three are correct; just different contexts?

Comment: @Dee: Yes, that is right.

Comment: I don't think the distinction is absolute though. In the following example I would take "observe" to mean "see, detect" rather than "say something in regard to": "I believe that scientific theories are a means of going -- somewhat mysteriously -- beyond what we are able to _observe of_ the physical world, penetrating into the structure of nature" (via [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/); [original source (link broken)](http://www.edge.org/q2005/q05_easyprint.html)).

Comment: @Fang Jing: *what we are able to observe of the physical world* can be reordered: *we are able to observe **what** of the physical world*. The preposition "of" there is not part of the verb phrase but belongs to the object-phrase.  Compare *I was able to hear some of what she said.* and *Of what she said I was able to hear some*. The verb there is not "hear of" but "hear". *Some of what...*"     You can substitute "that part" for "what" in your example about scientific theories.  "... that part ... of the physical world..."